# Android app crashes while scrolling down

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a blogging app for android and I am using firebase for the backend. The app is working fine but the when I scroll down to the last post, the app crashes. I have working on finding the solution from a quite a long but couldn't possibly find any.

**Here is the activity which is facing the problem**

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mStatusView;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;

    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    String userID = "";
    private Boolean exit = false;
    private Boolean mProcessLike = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);

                    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }

            }
        };

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Status");
        mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");

        mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mStatusView = findViewById(R.id.status_list);
        mStatusView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mStatusView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        checkUserExists();

        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

        // Creating a Firebase recycle Adapter
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Status, StatusViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Status, StatusViewHolder>(
                        Status.class,
                        R.layout.status_row,
                        StatusViewHolder.class,
                        mDatabase
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(StatusViewHolder viewHolder, Status model, int position) {

                        final String postKey = getRef(position).getKey();

                        viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                        viewHolder.setDescription((model.getDescription()));
                        viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

                        viewHolder.mNumberOfLikesTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        viewHolder.setLikeButton(postKey);
                        viewHolder.mLikeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                mProcessLike = true;
                                mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                        if (mProcessLike) {
                                            if (dataSnapshot.child(postKey).hasChild(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                                                mDatabaseLike.child(postKey).child(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                                                mProcessLike = false;
                                                Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Like removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            } else {
                                                mDatabaseLike.child(postKey).child(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("RandomValue");
                                                mProcessLike = false;
                                                Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Liked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

        mStatusView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    private void checkUserExists() {

        try {
            userID = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(userID)) {

                    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(UserActivity.this,
                            RegisterActivity.class);
                    registerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(registerIntent);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    // Setting up Recycler View
    public static class StatusViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        ImageButton mLikeButton;
        TextView mNumberOfLikesTextView;

        DatabaseReference mDataBaseLike;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;

        public StatusViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
            mLikeButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button);
            mNumberOfLikesTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_of_likes_text_view);

            mDataBaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            mDataBaseLike.keepSynced(true);
        }

        public void setLikeButton(final String postKey) {
            mDataBaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(postKey).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                        mLikeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_blue_24dp);
                    } else {
                        mLikeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_thumb_up_black_24dp);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }


        // Setting the title
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView statusTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.status_title_textView);
            statusTitle.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDescription(String desc) {
            TextView statusDescription = mView.findViewById(R.id.status_description_textView);
            statusDescription.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setImage(Context context, String image) {
            ImageView statusImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.status_image);

            Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(statusImage);

        }
    }
}
```

**And here is the log for the problem I'm getting**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.akash.iametderick, PID: 12384
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.akash.iametderick.Status
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzr.zzb(Unknown Source:842)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzr.zza(Unknown Source:0)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:22)
at com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(ObservableSnapshotArray.java:160)
at com.firebase.ui.database.CachingObservableSnapshotArray.getObject(CachingObservableSnapshotArray.java:40)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:180)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:217)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:285)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:342)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:358)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:365)
at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:396)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I've been trying to solve the problem from quite a long but couldn't find any solution.

**This is my status node:**

```
Status {
    -L10rFvy6N-t7RiF7FJ6 {
        date: ...;
        description: ...;
        image: ...;
        title: ...''
    }
    date: ...;
    description: ...;
    image: ...;
    title: ...''
}
```

Comment: Can you post your first node data and last node data in your firebase data ?

Comment: "Can't convert object of type" its type mismatch error .Debug your code and check your database.

Comment: Your error is `DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.akash.iametderick.Status` which means some data on your database is not in the correct format

Comment: Please add you database structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your data saved on firebase.

Your Node `Status` is a `Object` and you may have saved  its value as `long` for that particular node in your database.

So check you database and compare it with other node . Specially the node which is having the problem will be in last as you said `when I scroll down to the last pos` so check your last node